Filling the table using data from Pandas dataframe
I have to fill the table below using reports from each week. Instead of doing it manually I was trying to automate this process by writing few lines of code.
I've managed to aggregate the date from multiple input files and now I'm struggling to paste the numbers into table. Simple copy and transpose will not work as for some weeks there is no data.
I have such spreadsheet to fill in :
Spending report by week
| Budget name | Sum [h] | 1 | 2 | 3 |...
| -------- | -------- | ------|
| Team_a_expenses   | 1000  |
| Team_b_expenses| 1570  |
...
So far I've managed to aggregate the data:
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = r'C:\FUNDS'  # or unix / linux / mac path

# Get the files from the path provided in the OP
files = Path(path).glob('*.xlsx')  # .rglob to get subdirectories
dfs = list()
for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f)
    # .stem is method for pathlib objects to get the filename w/o the extension
    data['file'] = f.stem
    dfs.append(data)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df
grouped_series = df.groupby(['file', 'Activity week'])['Time'].sum()

#print(grouped_series)
df_grouped = grouped_series.to_frame()
# print(df_grouped)
df_grouped.to_excel("TEAM_spending.xlsx",
             sheet_name='Spending')

Results is :
Aggregated spending by budgets
I do not know how to iterate through all rows in column C and paste each value into appropriate cell into spending spreadsheet, based on activity week in columns and budget name in row.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Welcome to SO! [ask] recommends a [mre] with data as text, not images. Please use formating tools to make a table. Dataframes may be posted as the output of print(df)

Seems like you are nearly there and just need to .unstack your data, then apply a bit of formatting for the excel output.
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng(0)

# starting from your "df_grouped" variable
index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['Team_a_invest', 'Team_b_invest'], [*range(5)]],
    names=['Budget name', 'Productivity week'],
)
df_grouped = (
    pd.DataFrame(
       data={'Time': rng.normal(200, 40, size=len(index))},
       index=index,
    )
    .sample(frac=.9, random_state=rng) # introduce missing rows
    .sort_index()
)

print(
    df_grouped,
    #                                  Time
    # Budget name   Productivity week
    # Team_a_invest 0                  205.029209
    #               2                  225.616906
    #               3                  204.196005
    #               4                  178.573225
    # Team_b_invest 0                  214.463802
    #               1                  252.160002
    #               2                  237.883239
    #               3                  171.850591
    #               4                  149.383141

    (
        df_grouped['Time']
        .unstack(level='Productivity week')
        .assign(**{
            'Sum[h]': lambda d: d.sum(axis=1)
        })
        .fillna('')                                         # remove NaN values for easier copy/paste
        .loc[:, lambda d: [d.columns[-1], *d.columns[:-1]]] # put Sum[h] as first column
        .rename_axis(columns=None)                          # remove the name from the column Index (easier copy/paste)
        .reset_index()                                      # again, easier copy/paste
    ),
    #      Budget name       Sum[h]           0           1           2           3           4
    # 0  Team_a_invest   813.415345  205.029209              225.616906  204.196005  178.573225
    # 1  Team_b_invest  1025.740774  214.463802  252.160002  237.883239  171.850591  149.383141

    sep='\n\n'
)

Of course instead of a .groupby(…).unstack(…) pattern, you could also reach for a .pivot_table.
